# Select every option except for the selected one

Tags: jquery

How would I access every option of a select except the one that is selected?

I am trying, but with no success:

```
$('select[id^="buyingSupplierRef"]').live('mouseleave', function()
{
    $(this+' option:not(option:selected)').each(function(){
    $(this).detach() ;
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('option:not(:selected)', this).each(function(){
   // ...
})
```

Note that `live()` is deprecated, you can use `on()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `this + ' ...'` to do this, `this` is a DOM element. Instead, use `find`:

```
$(this).find('option:not(:selected)').each(function(){ ...
```

(Your selector, `option:not(option:selected)` was fine by you don't *have* to repeat the `option` bit, it has no effect; hence the above.)

Comment: @AnkitGautam: Either, it doesn't really matter. Wait, actually, it does: The `option` elements could be within [`optgroup` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-optgroup-element.html#the-optgroup-element), in which case `children` would fail but `find` would work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "option:not(:selected)", this).detach();
```

There is no need for `.each`, `.detach` will operate on all the elements anyway.